# Javascript - Strip certain strings from ".innerHTML" result

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have a function that's run on a button click. This function will get all of the HTML inside a certain element. That works fine. However, I would like to clean the returned string (HTML) up before using it further in my function:

```
exportHTML(){
  const element = document.getElementById('content');
  const innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
}
```

This works. But due to using Angular, Angular syntax is included within the HTML based on conditions in the source code. For example:

```
<div _ngcontent-c1=""></div>
```

OR

```
<div ng-reflect-klass="panel album"></div>
<div ng-reflect-ng-class="blue"></div>
```

Is it at all possible to filter these types of values out? In regards to the second and third example above, the classes within those would change quite often:

1. Is it possible to filter out and remove all **_ngcontent-c1=""** text
2. Is it possible to filter out and remove all **ng-reflect-klass** & **ng-reflect-ng-class** including the following open and closed quotes (to remove what's inside)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with RegExp

```js
const innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/ (_ngcon|ng-).*?".*?"/g, '');
```

1. `(_ngcon|ng-)` find `_ngcon` or `ng-` including space as first character
2. `.*?"` match everything until first `"`
3. `.*?"` and match everything again for the closing `"`

Comment: That's amazing. Once last thing, if it isn't too much trouble at all, how would I include  <!--bindings={
      "ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
      }--> in that replacement?

Comment: You can add `|<!--.*?-->` before the `/g`

Comment: Everything works about from the exclusion of the <!--bindings syntax. This is magic by the way.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the attributes would be constant but the values of the attributes would change?  If so, you could try this:

.replace(/ng-reflect-klass=\".*?\"/,"").replace(/ng-reflect-ng-class=\".*?\"/,"").replace(/_ngcontent-c1=\".*?\"/,"")

```js
var content = 'stuff<div ng-reflect-klass="panel album"></div><div ng-reflect-ng-class="blue"></div><div _ngcontent-c1=""></div>end stuff';

console.log(content.replace(/ng-reflect-klass=\".*?\"/g,"").replace(/ng-reflect-ng-class=\".*?\"/g,"").replace(/_ngcontent-c1=\".*?\"/g,""));
```

Look at the console to view the result.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution will remove all the attributes from element:

You can get all the [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) first. Then loop through them with [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). In each iteration, you can use [while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) loop to [`removeAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) until they are exist in the element.

Try the following way:

```js
function exportHTML(){
  const element = document.getElementById('content');
  const innerHTML = [].slice.call(element.children);
  innerHTML.forEach(function(el){
    while(el.attributes.length > 0)
      el.removeAttribute(el.attributes[0].name); 
  });
  console.log(document.getElementById('content').innerHTML); // output
}

exportHTML();
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div _ngcontent-c1=""></div>
  <div ng-reflect-klass="panel album"></div>
  <div ng-reflect-ng-class="blue" another-test></div>
  <span test="test-element"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, @Mamun. Neat usage of `[...element.children]`, didn't know this technique until now (Spread Operator). It's an ES6 feature and cross-browser support would be a problem, wouldn't it?

Comment: @FlavioCysne, using `[].slice.call()` will solve the cross-browser issue....updated the answer......thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/flaviocysne/bmdLv6c3/) as an example of how to do this without using jQuery.

Using the HTML code below as an example

```
<div id="origin-content">
  <div id="div1" _ngcontent-c1="">Content 1</div>
  <div id="div2" ng-reflect-klass="panel album">Content 2</div>
  <div id="div3" ng-reflect-ng-class="blue">Content 3</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="target-content">
</div>
```

I extracted all children from `origin-content` and copied them to `target-content` using the code that follows.

```
var result = document.getElementById('target-content');
var elems = document.querySelector('#origin-content').children;
var count = elems.length;

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  var val = elems[i];
  val.removeAttribute('_ngcontent-c1');
  val.removeAttribute('ng-reflect-klass');
  val.removeAttribute('ng-reflect-ng-class');
  result.innerHTML += val.outerHTML;
}
```

There is still plenty of room for improvement.

I hope it helps to solve the OP question.